# Couldn't create a subtheme of a core theme

Tags: theming

I want to do some customization on seven administation theme, I won't to copy it in my themes folder, I want to create a subtheme of it, it doesn't work for me. this is my info file

```
name = SEVEN SUB
description = a Seven subtheme
base theme = seven
core = 7.x
stylesheets[all][] = style.css
```

when I replace Seven by a theme already exists in my sites/all/themes, my theme inherits it, but for core themes it doesn't.
I tried to specify the path of seven, themes/seven and /themes/seven doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Your .info file looks OK, so it must be something else. Is the machine name  of the theme (the name before the .info) the same as an existing theme or module? That could cause a problem. Also, it the name should be only lower-case, digits and underscore. (No space or other punctuation.)

Comment: The same sub theme works good when I change the base theme name to a contrib theme. I'm using D7.4.1 can u please try create a seven subtheme in your drupal installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal 7 if subtheme is attaching CSS with exact same file name, Drupal thinks you want to override a CSS file. That seems to be the problem for you. So you are overriding the CSS from the Seven theme by attaching `style.css` in the info file.

Easiest way to get over that problem is to rename your CSS file into something else e.g. `seven_sub.style.css`.